# Python: Converting a queryset in a list of tuples

Tags: python, django, performance

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField()
```

How to get email and name of User as a list of tuples? My current solution is this:

```
result = []
for user in User.objects.all():
    result.append((user.email, user.name))
```

Comment: What if you have more than one key/value pair, do you only want x and y?

Comment: `for` loops are still okay to use in python. Not everything has to be a one liner

Comment: To shorten the code use list comprehension instead of for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) for this:

```
result = User.objects.all().values_list("email", "name")
```

Answer (score 9):

If this is an django ORM queryset (or result of it), you can just use `values_list` method instead of `values`. That will give exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `queryset` is supposed to look like this, with `'x'` and `'y'` as string keys:

```
>>> queryset = [{'x':'1', 'y':'a'}, {'x':'2', 'y':'b'}]
>>> result = [(q['x'], q['y']) for q in queryset]
>>> result
[('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b')]
>>> # or if x and y are actually the correct names/vars for the keys
... result = [(q[x], q[y]) for q in queryset]
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly what is was searching for

Answer (score 5):

If you can have multiple keys and you just want certain key values, you can use *itemgetter* with map passing the keys  you want to extract:

```
from operator import itemgetter
result = list(map(itemgetter("x", "y"), queryset)))
```

Answer (score 2):

`your_tuple = [(x.get('attrA'), x.get('attrB')) for x in queryset.values()]`

Comment: `queryset` is a `list` not a `dict`

Comment: `[(x, y) for x, y in queryset.items()]` would give you the same as `list(queryset.items())` which is the key/value not the values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dict.values()`:

```
queryset = [{x:'1',y:'a'}, {x:'2',y:'b'}]
result = []

for i in queryset:
    result.append(tuple(i.values()))
```

Or in one line:

```
result = [tuple(i.values()) for i in queryset]
```

---

If you want them in a particular order:

`result = [(i[x], i[y]) for i in queryset]`

Comment: `i.values()` won't necessarily return the 'x' value before the 'y' value so you it can sometimes give `[('a', '1'), ('b', '2')]` (or some combo like that), instead of `[('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b')]`

Comment: In your edited answer, `((i[y], i[x]))` is the wrong order. But anyway, what you've put as the edit is the **same thing** the OP has in his question.

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension and `dict.values()`

```
>>> queryset = [{'x': '1', 'y': 'a'}, {'x': '2', 'y': 'b'}]
>>> result = [tuple(v.values()) for v in queryset]
>>> result
    [('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b')]
```

**UPDATE**

as @aneroid reasonably mentioned, since `dict` object are not ordered the code snippet could return different order in `tuple`

So since i don't want to add duplicate solution. There is one option, not so elegant, and maybe with a lack of efficiency, to use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> queryset = [{'x': '1', 'y': 'a'}, {'x': '2', 'y': 'b'}]
>>> order = ('x', 'y')
>>> result = [tuple(OrderedDict((k, v[k]) for k in myorder).values()) for v in queryset]
>>> result
    [('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b')]
```

But i personally think that @PadraicCunningham 's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39702851/3124746) is the most elegant here.

Comment: `v.values()` won't necessarily return the 'x' value before the 'y' value so you it can sometimes give `[('a', '1'), ('b', '2')]` (or some combo like that), instead of `[('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b')]`