# Generate iterable choices tuple from model class in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, tuples

I'm working on a django model and I want to generate a tuple out of my model instances :

**model.py**

```
class Extra(models.Model):
    extra_n = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    extra_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.extra_n
```

The output I'm expecting based on the user entries on the form associated  :

```
choices = (('extra_price 1','extra_n1'),
           ('extra_price 2','extra_n2'),
           ('extra_price 3','extra_n3')
)
```

Comment: You have some entries in `Extra` model and you want to create tuple from all entries from`Extra` model. Is it?

Comment: @ShafikurRahman yes exactly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Converting a queryset in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702538/python-converting-a-queryset-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an ORM call with [**`.values_list(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
tuple(Extra.objects.values_list('extra_price', 'extra_n'))
```

That being said, Django forms can work with a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) that will make choices itself based on the model (or a filtered queryset if you provide one).

Comment: I'm having this error :

     
       extras = MultiSelectField(choices=tuple(ex.objects.values_list('extra_p', 'extra_n')))
  File "/Users/pc/Desktop/code 2 copy/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 186, in __get__
    raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % cls.__name__)

AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Extra instances

Comment: You should not use an `Extra` *object*, but the `Extra` class. You can see `.objects` as a static member (although it is a bit more complicated than that).

Comment: @trusted: you import the `Extra` class, and thus use `MultiSelectField(choices=tuple(Extra.objects.values_list('extra_p', 'extra_n')))`...

Comment: how can I import a model class into another model which are in the same models.py file ?

Comment: @trusted: you don't. If the class is defined *before* that one, then it is "implicitly" imported (well it is defined), if it is defined later, then you should reorder it. if however you use a reference to the class in a function, then evaluation is postponed, hence the *symbol table resolution* step will deal with that.

Comment: That being said, using this in combination with a `MultiSelectField` does not only makes no sense at all (and will not update when new `Extra`s are added at runtime). It furthermore will also result in a denormalized database and in ineffective database with data duplication and an ineffective ORM. You should use a `ForeignKey` when you aim to reference model objects. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/