# Django ORM Query , how to convert the query set to tuple of tuples

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to do this from query

(('1','A'), ('2','B'), ....)

to use it as choice field in my form, how to convert my query result to do this ?

where 1,2 is the row id and A,B is another columns value

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702538/python-converting-a-queryset-in-a-list-of-tuples) but I change simple thing

```
[(q['x'], q['y']) for q in query]
```

to

```
tuple((q['x'], q['y']) for q in query)
```